# How do I create an auto-implemented list property in a class in C#?

Tags: c#, list, class, properties

To begin with I made a class with fields like this:

```
class Person
{
    public string name;
    public List<Thing> things = new List<Thing>();

    public Person(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

and directly changed the field `things` outside the class, but later found out that this is not the best practice as the fields of class should be private and accessed using public properties instead. I decided to change these fields into auto-implemented properties, as I currently don't require any validation within the properties:

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Thing> Things { get; set; }

    public Person(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }
}
```

According the MSDN page for auto-implemented properties (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx), the compiler creates a private backing field for the property.

However, with a list property **I'm not sure whether the compiler automatically instantiates the list backing field**, so my question is **will having the lists as auto-implemented properties work as in the second example above**, or **do I need to instantiate the lists as well**, and if so how should I do this?

Comment: Yes, you need to instantiate, in the constructor for example

Comment: Instantiate - usually in the constructor

Comment: Also, you probably want to make the property `{ get; private set; }`

Comment: Note that C# 6 (when it's released) will add syntax to allow this: `public List<Thing> Things { get; private set; } = new List<Thing>();`

Comment: @Ruben9922 To prevent that a new list is created and assigned to the `Things` property from outside the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm not sure whether the compiler automatically instantiates the list backing field

It doesn't. If you don't instantiate it, it will be null by default.

> do I need to instantiate the lists as well, and if so how should I do this?

You need to instantiate it yourself. This is usually/can be done in the constructor. E.g:

```
public Person(string name) 
{
    this.Name = name;
    this.Things = new List<Thing>();
}
```

Comment: Oh right, would it be better to instantiate it outside the constructor though, when the property is declared?

Comment: You can't instantiate the list directly when you use auto-implemented properties (That will be possible in C# 6 though). So you either have to implement the property yourself (declare your own backing field and instantiate that) or instantiate it in the constructor (or another method). I would prefer the auto-implemented property and constructor initialization. One isn't "better" than the other, it is a matter of opinion.